# Is_front_page inside header.php is always returning true

Tags: php, headers, conditional-content, frontpage

I have a page that I designated as my front page using the `reading` portion of settings in the dashboard. When I place a script inside of an if statement using `is_front_page` in functions.php, it only runs on that designated front-page, and not the others (indicating the page has been designated correctly).

However, I have an `if` statement in my header.php file that also uses `is_front_page`, and that seems to be triggering on all my pages (including the ones that I have not designated as the front page).

What is going on? Can you not run `is_front_page` from within header.php and have that code only apply to the front-page header? Am I missing something?

This is the code that I have placed in my header.php file that is returning true on all pages

`<?php echo ( is_front_page ) ?  'frontPageLogo' : NULL; ?>`

(I believe it is returning true on all pages because it always echoes 'frontPageLogo')

Comment: There seem to be either some round brackets missing or in the wrong position in the code line you posted.

Comment: the ternary statement should have had `is_front_page()` (with parentheses)

Comment: jHoffmann & czerspalace you were both right, thank you, those got my ternary statement working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it should work in the header file just like normal.  Try using a standard IF statement instead of shorthand:

```
if( is_front_page() ){
    echo 'Front page!';
}
```

You must have it configured in the settings to use:

`A static page (select below)` instead of `Your latest posts`

If you want `is_front_page()` to only return TRUE when viewing the page you select from the dropdown for **Front Page** (which it sounds like you do)

You can then use `is_home()` if a static page is set for the front page of the site, this function will return true only on the page you set as the “Posts page”.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/

Whether [is_home()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/) or [is_front_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/) return `true` or `false` depends on the values of certain option values:

- `get_option( 'show_on_front' )`: returns either `'posts'` or `'page'`
- `get_option( 'page_on_front' )`: returns the `ID` of the static page assigned to the front page
- `get_option( 'page_for_posts' )`: returns the `ID` of the static page assigned to the blog posts index (posts page)

When using these query conditionals:

- If `'posts' == get_option( 'show_on_front' )`:

  - On the site front page:

    - `is_front_page()` will return `true`
    - `is_home()` will return `true`
  - If assigned, WordPress ignores the pages assigned to display the site front page or the blog posts index
- If `'page' == get_option( 'show_on_front' )`:

  - On the page assigned to display the site front page:

    - `is_front_page()` will return `true`
    - `is_home()` will return `false`
  - On the page assigned to display the blog posts index:

    - `is_front_page()` will return `false`
    - `is_home()` will return `true`

Comment: when you say I must "have it configured" do you mean the front-page or the other pages. As I said is_front_page works exclusively on the designated front page when I use functions.php file. It is only the header.php that is acting strangely.

Comment: Ok, the code you posted only fired on front-page when I inserted in on header-php so there is something wrong with my ternary statement. Nothing seems to be wrong with the static settings, they are all as they should be. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, your original statement would have worked if you had called a function by including parens instead of using what looked like a non-existent constant to the PHP interpreter.  The constant *is_front_page* was evaluated as the string "is_front_page" and since "is_front_page" is not == false, it evaluated as true and "frontPageLogo" was always echoed. Get it?

So instead of:

```
<?php echo ( is_front_page ) ?  'frontPageLogo' : NULL; ?>
```

You wanted:

```
   <?php echo ( is_front_page() ) ?  'frontPageLogo' : NULL; ?>
```